# HttpWebResponse GetResponseStream hanging in Dispose

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am using `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream` to access an internet radio stream, and want to read some data from the response stream, and then disconnect. However, I always hang indefinitely on the Dispose of the stream. The unit test below will display "Cleaning up networkStream...", but never get to "Finished". Why is this? And should I fix it by just not bothering to Dispose of my networkStream?

```
[Test]
public void CanStreamMP3Radio()
{
    string url = @"http://radio.reaper.fm/stream/";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    int total = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    using(var networkStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        do
        {
            int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytesRead", bytesRead);
            total += bytesRead;
        } while (total < 16384);
        Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up networkStream...");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue.
I know you've fixed it using `req.Abort();` but I'm wondering **why** the code hangs when disposing the response stream in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: just found a solution... call `req.Abort()` before the end of the `using` block. Not very elegant, but it works... So the code becomes:

```
[Test]
public void CanStreamMP3Radio()
{
    string url = @"http://radio.reaper.fm/stream/";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        int total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        var networkStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        do
        {
            int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytesRead", bytesRead);
            total += bytesRead;
        } while (total < 16384);
        Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up HttpWebResponse...");
        req.Abort();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

---

<strike>Try disposing the `HttpWebResponse` instead:</strike>

```
[Test]
public void CanStreamMP3Radio()
{
    string url = @"http://radio.reaper.fm/stream/";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        int total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        var networkStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        do
        {
            int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytesRead", bytesRead);
            total += bytesRead;
        } while (total < 16384);
        Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up HttpWebResponse...");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

It should dispose the `NetworkStream` as well.

Comment: This one hangs too - I don't get to "Finished"

Comment: Just tried it, I'm getting the same result on this URL... weird

Comment: thanks, that does the trick - do you want to edit that into your code sample, & I'll mark as answer